# magento multiple domain installation help

Tags: magento-2.1, multidomain

I really need some help in order to setup multiple domain with single installation setup. 
I followed all i could find throughout web but yet it seems i am missing something.

This is regarding magento CE 2.1 clean install .using 2 domain with 2 store. I followed all the information i could find on the net .. i added needed code to index.php of root installation and htaccess . site works ok but when i use second domain , i get redirected back to my main domain

Comment: Thanks. This is regarding magento  CE 2.1 clean install  .using 2 domain with 2 store. I followed all the information i could find on the net ..
i added needed code to index.php of root installation  and htaccess . site works ok but when i use second domain , i get redirected back to my main domain .

Answer (score 1):

well. i see mangento 2.1 has many bugs. so i decided to use magento 2. i really don't believe anyone knows how to setup mangento with multiple domain . there are so many site out there that just copy past from poorly done mangento 2 documentation . only to have a something on their site just so they can show adds. 
there might be possibility of doing what i need with only heavy hacking the core , thats how i been convinced after 2 weeks of search and try .

might have to look for other CMS / Cart system that dose this.

stay away from CE 2.1  has many admin issues.